# How to read all new files of a directory with python?

Tags: python, xml, operating-system, lxml, glob

I'm beginner in Python and I'm wondering to know how can I add a condition in this code to read only all new files of `.../data/` directory (for example from 24 hours ago) or (from last execution time). Because I parse my `.xml` files every day and it is parsing all old files again and it takes time.

```
from lxml import etree as ET
import glob
import sys
import os

path = '/home/sky/data/'

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml')):
    try:
        tree = ET.parse(filename)
        root = tree.getroot()

        #other codes here

    except Exception:
        pass
```

Thanks!

Comment: A better technique would be to simply move files once they have been processed. For example, have the files delivered to `.../incoming/`, then move them to `.../data` after you have processed them. That way, your script just works with whatever it finds in `.../incoming`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml')):
    if os.path.getmtime(filename) < time.time() - 24 * 60 * 60:  # 24h ago
        continue  # skip the old file
    ...
```

Comment: Minor optimization/gotcha (depending on the runtime of the program/number of files being traversed): `time.time()` will get called every time around the loop, thus the cut-off time will continually be changing.  This can both lead to unexpected output if this program runs for a long time over many files, and is also inefficient (albeit not unreasonably so) by re-doing that computation.  Would recommend extracting `time.time() - 24 * 60 * 60` up outside of the loop.

Comment: @BowlingHawk95
Python will automatically calculate the constant values in compile time, and cache the result, so the computation will only happen once (when loading the program). I agree regarding the cut-off time being dynamic.